# How to open the default email app on Android from Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, email, package

I have a button and I would like to press it to open the dafult application of the phone emails.
I tried to search online but I only find references to the url_launcher package which, from what I understand, allows you to open the email app and automatically write to someone, but I don't want this, I just want to open the email app and leave it on the main screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that `url_launcher` can only be used to create messages. But the plugin [`android_intent_plus`](https://pub.dev/packages/android_intent_plus) can help you only open the email app

```
import 'dart:io' show Platform;
```

```
if (Platform.isAndroid) {
  AndroidIntent intent = AndroidIntent(
    action: 'android.intent.action.MAIN',
    category: 'android.intent.category.APP_EMAIL',
  );
  intent.launch().catchError((e) {
     print("Error opening email app: $e");
  });
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for the reply, I tried to do as you say but it gives me 2 errors, the first is that it does not understand the .isAndroid at first, and even if I porov to remove it and make it go it gives me this error:
Error opening email app: MissingPluginException (No implementation found for method launch on channel dev.fluttercommunity.plus/android_intent)

Comment: You will need to import the dart:io package and the android_intent_plus package. Afterwards, delete the app from your device and reinstall it so that the plugin is correctly loaded

Comment: thank you very much, now it works perfectly, just one last question if I can, when I press the button that should open the app it does not open the gmail app but it opens gmail inside my application, this happens because I still use the application by starting it from IntellijIDEA and do not use a real apk file yet or is it done on purpose like this? And if it was done on purpose, is there a method to open gmail as an external app?

Comment: I beiliege you will have to set the flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK. This can be passed as an argument to the AndroidIntent() constructor.

Comment: could you write me what to write and at what precise point, sorry if I bother you so much but I'm quite new to programming 

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using the [url launcher package](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher), after installing it and following the steps of setting it up on your target devices.

use this method:

```
     Future<void> sendMailto({
    String email = "mail@example.com",
  }) async {
    final String emailSubject = "some subject here";
    final Uri parsedMailto = Uri.parse(
        "mailto:<$email>?subject=$emailSubject");

    if (!await launchUrl(
      parsedMailto,
      mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication,
    )) {
      throw "error"
    }
  }
```

now the user will face a popup containing mail services app options to choose.
If the user chooses a default mail app on his device, he will be redirected to it automatically.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for the reply, I tried to do as you say but it gives me 1 error, it says that encodeQueryParameters isn't defined

Comment: try the new full method

Answer (score 0):

For android to work just add https://pub.dev/packages/android_intent_plus inside your pubspec.yaml

This method will open the Gmail app on the Android & Mailboxes on IOS devices.

```
Future<void> openEmail() async {   if (Platform.isAndroid) {
    const AndroidIntent intent = AndroidIntent(
      action: 'android.intent.action.MAIN',
      category: 'android.intent.category.APP_EMAIL',
    );
    await intent.launch().catchError((e) {
      logger.f("Error opening email app: $e");
    });   } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
    await launchUrlWithTarget(target: '', url: 'message://');   } }

Future<void> launchUrlWithTarget(
    {required String target, required String url}) async {
  final Uri uri = Uri.parse('$url:$target');
  logger.f(uri);

  if (await canLaunchUrl(uri)) {
    await launchUrl(uri);
  }
}
```